# Relation between two numbers.

Tags: number-theory

Let $0 \lt x \lt 1$ and $0 \lt \delta \lt 1$ two real numbers. Can I always find something like $x\lt c\delta^2 \lt 1$, where $c$ is a constant that doesn't involve $\delta$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's only true if $x=0$. Suppose you found a constant $c$ that only depends on $x$, so you have $x<c\delta^2<1$ for all $\delta$. Now for that fixed $x$, pick $\delta=\sqrt{x}$, so $c>1$. Now pick $\delta=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2c}}$ (notice that $x/c<1$ and hence $0<\delta<1$). So you'll get $x<x/2$,  $\mbox{   }$  uh-oh.